# Creating Custom OSM Map Stylesheet (Ubuntu tileserver)

Tags: openstreetmap, carto, mapbox, ubuntu

I have researched, but not found yet a way to create custom stylesheets like ex.:

**OSMBright**, or **carto-openstreetmap** stylesheets, and integrate it on my own ***Ubuntu Tileserver*** from Openstreetmap data.

At the moment I am using **Carto-Openstreetmap** stylesheet. Any information on how can I achieve creating a new custom designed differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im assuming you want a map style written in CartoCSS which is what openstreetmap-carto is written in.

There are several ways to do this. I have used [Mapbox Studio Classic](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio-classic/) in the past. Mapbox does like you to serve tiles from their own platform - there are ways to export to your own server. [Tilelive](https://github.com/mapbox/tilelive) and [Tessera](https://github.com/mojodna/tessera) are possibilities.

[Kosmtik](https://github.com/kosmtik/kosmtik) is another option - i have no experience with this though and I would really recommend using mapbox.